# BOOST request sending JSON data

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to transfer json data into request of json boost in cpp.

If i take json in boost

```
int outer=2;

value data = {
        {"dia",outer},
        {"sleep_time_in_s",0.1}
    };

request.body()=data;
```

like above i want to send data from boost client to server , but it's through error
is any one understand below error suggest me .

```
error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

C:\Boost\boost/beast/core/multi_buffer.hpp(360,25): message : could be 'boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>> &boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>>::operator =(const boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>> &)'

2>C:\Boost\boost/beast/core/multi_buffer.hpp(345,5): message : or       'boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>> &boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>>::operator =(boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>> &&)'

2>C:\Development\qa-cal\sysqa_cpp\src\guiClient\boostHttpClient.cpp(90,31): message : while trying to match the argument list '(boost::beast::basic_multi_buffer<std::allocator<char>>, std::string)'
```

Comment: If you ask questions about build errors, first of all please create a proper [mre], that replicates the error you want to ask about and *only* the error you want to ask about. Then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log into the question (together with the code of course). And lastly add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: Also please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: It looks like the error is from a different line of code, because it says you're trying to assign std::string to a multi_buffer which is certainly not happening in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is strongly typed. You cannot assign a `json::value` to something else. In this case your `body()` is likely something like `std::string`.

Assuming that `value` is `boost::json::value` you should write something like:

```
request.body() = serialize(data);
```

Where `boost::json::serialize` serializes the `data` value into string representation.

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21b726abba12a7de)**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace http = boost::beast::http;

int main() {
    using boost::json::value;
    http::request<http::string_body> request(
            http::verb::post, "/some/api", 11);

    {
        int outer = 2;
        value data  = {
            {"dia", outer},
            {"sleep_time_in_s", 0.1},
        };
        request.body() = serialize(data);
    }

    request.prepare_payload();

    std::cout << request;
}
```

Prints

```
POST /some/api HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 32
{"dia":2,"sleep_time_in_s":1E-1}
```

Comment: How to post images

Comment: Where ? I just paste them into my post, or put them on imgur.com and use the link. If it's about programming you probably should ask a new question (because JSON isn't an image). And [don't forget to vote/accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your question was answered.

Comment: I want to send the image data same like above                                                          
  value data  = {{"photo1", image_base64 converted}}     in post request for this what is the context type and if i want to wrap up as a dictionary in cpp(string and  base64 image data)

Comment: Yeah, nothing about my answer changes. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3992fa6b4e7ea48

Comment: Thanks for response it's worked for me and I am try to send continuous data  using threads it's no responds

Comment: I don't doubt you. If you want someone to help, you'll need to show self-contained code that demonstrates the problem, and post that as a new question.